# django admin remove login page

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway to delete django admin login page (mySite.com/admin) and use the user session which has logged in in main site (mySite.com)?

If any code is needed please tell me to add.

My middleware in `settings.py` is:

```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
              .
              .
              .
              .
              .
    ]
```

---

*update*:

the reason is I want the admin first logs in with his account in website then open admin page. Other users would see admin link, but after clicking that they would see a message `you don't have permission to see or change anything` and they see nothing else. I just want `myWebsite.com/admin` be redirected to `admin:index` if the user is logged in and to `myWebsite.com` if he is not.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this using your main urls.py file. Just redirect the admin login URL to your custom log-in page on your website. In the below sample you will notice the normal admin.site.urls being used AFTER admin/login and admin/logout (I assume you'll also have a custom log-out page). With these custom views being first they will take precedence and be used instead of the ones in admin.site.urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/login', your_custom_login_view, name='custom_login_page_admin'),
    url(r'^admin/logout', your_custom_logout_view, name='custom_logout_view_admin'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom subclass of `AdminSite` and overwrite the `login()` method. Something like this:

```
class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def login(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            # not authenticated, redirect to main login page
            login_path = reverse('login')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(login_path)
        if self.has_permission(request):
            # Already logged-in, redirect to admin index
            index_path = reverse('admin:index', current_app=self.name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(index_path)
        else:
            # Logged in, but doesn't have required permissions
            return render(...)  # render a template with your error message
```

Follow the Django documentation on [how to customize the AdminSite class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class).

Comment: where should this `CustomAdminSite` be located? Is there any other change needed?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do that? Admin Page is for admin purposes, just dont access /admin/ path anymore or just remove admin from your `urls.py`, doign that you will not be able to access admin pages anymore...

But if you want to make your users access your django admin native pages using your custom login page, just make sure to tag your users with is_staff so they can access native django pages...

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(User):
    ... # Your new fields
```

**views.py**

```
def create_user(request):
    ...
    user, created = CustomUser.objects.get_or_created(
        ... # Your Custom + User Django fields
        is_staff = True # This will allow this user to access the admin page
    )
```

If you want allow all your users to access your django admin pages without need to use Django Login Page you can override your CustomUser model to set all users with `is_staff`

```
class CustomUser(User):
        ... # Your new fields

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id: # This indentify if the registry is new...
                self.is_staff = True
            super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Obs.: Make sure your User models extends the Django User Auth, there 2... one more complex and one simple, check the docs**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Make a mix between my answer and scharette answer... or just call your admin url by other name like /login/ but to your use see the admin pages you need to make sure they have is_staff = True, and he user is authenticated...

Comment: Other way is to override Django Admin Login Page, and place your CSS and structure there, so that way django loads this page without you need to do nothing else

Answer (score 0):

All mentioned solutions here might do a good job, but my solution would be a little different: If you want to redirect to your default login page and hide the django-admin, sth. simple like this is a good workaround:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('admin/login/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='account_login', permanent=True)),
]
```

Of course the target route (here `account_login`) can be changed as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach:

on urls.py

```
from .settings import LOGIN_URL
from django.views.generic import RedirectView,
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/login/', RedirectView.as_view(url=LOGIN_URL)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ....
]
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable admin just remove `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` from your main `urls.py`. Another things to clean are `'django.contrib.admin'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I'm not gonna disable it, I just want the login page be omitted and users log in from base website and use that session for admin page.. check my question update

Answer (score -2):

A real easy way to accomplish this is by doing **2 things**:

1. Head to your settings.py file and add: `ADMIN_ENABLED = False`
2. Head to your main `urls.py` file which should have something that looks like:

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("landing.urls")),
]
```

and `comment out` the **path to admin** like in the above snippet.

Cheers!